# A build operation failed. Failed to notify dependency resolution listener

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I am trying to build my java project and I keep on receiving the error below.

```
A build operation failed.
    Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencySubstitutions$Substitution.with(Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/component/ComponentSelector;)
```

I've tried changing version of `gradle` to all available version with no luck.

My Project (root) `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


myapp build.gradle

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spacester.tweetster"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    //noinspection GradleDependency,GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.2.4'
    //implementation project(path: ':nativetemplates')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.hendraanggrian.appcompat:socialview:0.3-rc1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.tylersuehr7:social-text-view:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
    //noinspection GradleDependency,GradleDependency
    implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:3.1.2'
    implementation 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.5'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you try updating your dependencies, and that you have the latest versions of gradle and the dependencies. Then try resync the project then rebuild.

Comment: yes i did updated everything

Comment: hi Adam hope you see this but I am concerned as I cannot see your discord what happened?